Any two subdivisions of a simplicial complex has a common subdivision
I am reading Munkres' Elements of Algebraic Topology. In his book (chapter 15), the subdivision of a simplicial complex $K$ is defined as another complex $K'$ such that each simplex of $K'$ is contained in a simplex of $K$, and each simplex of $K$ equals the union of finitely many simplices of $K'$.
Meanwhile, I note from Bryant's Handbook of Geometric Topology (chapter 5) that any two subdivisions $L$ and $J$ of $K$ have a common subdivision.
This seems to be obvious heuristically, since subdivision are dividing the simplices in $K$, and we can just take the more fragmental division at each simplex of $K$. However, I failed to find a way to formulate it under the definition of Munkres.
Could you please provide a proof of this, or some literature I can refer to? Thanks a lot.

After all, it seems that this MSE thread has settled my question.
